# Append an int to char*

Tags: c++, integer, char, append

How would you append an integer to a `char*` in c++?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First convert the int to a `char*` using `sprintf()`:

```
char integer_string[32];
int integer = 1234;

sprintf(integer_string, "%d", integer);
```

Then to append it to your other char*, use `strcat()`:

```
char other_string[64] = "Integer: "; // make sure you allocate enough space to append the other string

strcat(other_string, integer_string); // other_string now contains "Integer: 1234"
```

Comment: You have a buffer overflow vulnerability on your hands if sizeof(int) > 4.

Comment: @Tom: I'm not used to using the int type (I always use types like u8, u16, u32, etc.) so I didn't think of that... I will change the size of the string then.

Comment: Should use snprintf and strncat, just to be safe.

Comment: why not do it all via the sprintf?? snprintf(other_string, 64, "Interger: %d", integer);

Comment: Instead of using a fixed constant size for the string, you might want to use something like <base size>+sizeof(int)*3+1 (3 = ceil(8*log10(2)), 1 for '-'). This should always work (also in case of 128-bit ints etc.) and also avoids unnecessarily large allocations (probably not an issue).

Comment: For added portability, multiply that factor 3 by CHAR_BITS/8.

Comment: This is quite old. I tried and it show 'unsafe to use' on strcat and sprintf. Any latest answer would be good.

Answer (score 10):

You could also use stringstreams.

```
char *theString = "Some string";
int theInt = 5;
stringstream ss;
ss << theString << theInt;
```

The string can then be accessed using `ss.str();`

Comment: That returns string instead of char *

Answer (score 4):

Something like:

```
width = floor(log10(num))+1;
result = malloc(strlen(str)+len));
sprintf(result, "%s%*d", str, width, num);
```

You could simplify len by using the maximum length for an integer on your system.

*edit* oops - didn't see the "++". Still, it's an alternative.