# Append integer to end of const char* c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, char, append

I have  `const char* FilePathName` which looks like this: `C:\ImportantFile.hex`
And an `int id = 12345;`
I need to define a new `const char* FilePathName_ID` that would append the id with an underscore to the original `FilePathName` to look like this:  `C:\ImportantFile_12345.hex`
I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347132/append-an-int-to-char) but its different as I am using const char* which gives me the error `cannot convert from 'const char * ' to 'char'`and need an underscore.
I need to end up with a `const char*`
**EDIT** I need to keep the file extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a new `std::string` object or a null-terminated byte string. One easy way is this:

```
std::string append_number(std::string const& x, unsigned int num, char sep = '_') {
    std::stringstream s;
    s << strip_extension(x) << sep << num;
    return s.str();
}
```

You can pass a string literal to the above function seamlessly.

Update: I notice that you probably also need to strip the extension:

```
std::string strip_extension(std::string x, char ext_sep = '.') {
     return x.substr(0, x.find_last_of(ext_sep));
}

std::string get_extension(std::string const& x, char ext_sep = '.') {
     return x.substr(x.find_last_of(ext_sep) + 1); // no error checking 
}
```

See updated definition of `append_number`.

Update 2: Try the following program:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::string strip_extension(std::string const& x, char ext_sep = '.') {
     return x.substr(0, x.find_last_of(ext_sep));
}

std::string append_number(std::string const& x, unsigned int num, char sep = '_') {
        std::stringstream s;
        s << strip_extension(x) << sep << num << '.' << get_extension(x);
        return s.str();
    }

int main() {
  std::cout << append_number("file.hex", 45) << std::endl;
}
```

The output should be:

```
file_45.hex
```

Comment: I need a const char* in the end though.

Comment: @Nick S.: That's easy: `const char *s = append_number( ... ).c_str()`. Fill up the `...` with your own variables.

Comment: You can simply call `c_str()` at the end to get a `const char *`

Comment: @dirkgently thanks, I forgot to add the extension fixed now. I'll try this.

Comment: `s<<sep<<x;` I guess it should be `s<<sep<<num`.

Comment: @Cedric H.: Spot on! Virtual beer for you mate.

Comment: This still isn't working for me. I get this:  

-  newfilepathname 0x007E97B0 "ÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝ " char*  

 in the watch window.

Comment: @Nick S.: Hm. There was a bug w.r.t extension stripping. Posted a minimal compilable example. Try that out.

Comment: @Nick S. Are you creating a separate declaration for the functions too? Then remove the `= ...` part from the definition of the functions.

Comment: The example I posted compiles w/o such warnings on GCC, Comeau and VS2010.

Comment: I got it to compile but I still get the same error with the YYYY's ugh.

Comment: @Nick S.:What compiler are you using? What inputs are you passing? You are not using wide character string literals, are you?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2008. I think I've fond another way to do it using strings.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're hitting an error. Do check the updated source if you want to get the extension as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up using strings and appended() and inserted() not elegant but it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ostringstream oss;
 oss << FilePathName << "_" < id;
 const char* FilePathNameID = oss.str().c_str();
```

Answer (score 0):

As mikerobi said, you can use sprintf to deal with it:

```
char szAppended[MAX_PATH+10]; // ensure to have enough space for the path and ID
char szNoExt[MAX_PATH];
strcpy(szNoExt, FilePathName);
char *pExt = strrchr(szNoExt, '.');
*pExt = '\0';
sprintf(szAppended, "%s_%d.%s", szNoExt, id, pExt + 1);
```

You should probably also add some memory checks for the existence of extension.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Any const char * returned via 'c_str()' from a std::string will only be valid as long as the std::string is in scope. You can obtain the pointer but after the string is gone it will be garbage.

You should be able to pass a char * into a function taking a const char * - it sounds like the primary issue may be creating/keeping a valid pointer.

Comment: I think this is where I'm having trouble.

Comment: A very hackish way to accomplish this would be to create a global instance of a std::string and use one of the solutions above to set its contents. After this the pointer should remain valid. However I would recommend trying to understand the scope problem, or possibly changing to use std::strings passed around by reference or value where appropriate.