# how to add a int to a char[] in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, char

i have a code like this:

```
int i = 123;
char myString[100];
strcpy(myString, "my text");
```

and how i want to add the 123 after "my text". how to do this in c/c++?

at the end `myString` sould be `my test123`

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages.  They way you would do this in C is completely different from how you'd do it in C++.

Comment: If C++, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347132/append-an-int-to-char

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(To complement Luchian's answer)

In C:

```
char myString[128];
int i = 123;
snprintf(myString, sizeof(myString), "My Text %d", i);
```

Comment: Note: this only works if `myString` is an array.  If it's a pointer instead, you must keep track of the length of the pointed-to buffer and pass that in as the second argument of `snprintf`, since `sizeof(pointer)` is not what you want (it's typically 4 or 8 bytes).

Comment: Yeah, I was just adding clarification in case anyone came by and decided to copy+paste the code without fully understanding it.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield valid reason, absolutely. (NO ONE should copy-paste code without understanding it though, right?)

Answer (score 8):

In C++:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "my text" << i;
std::string resultingString = ss.str();
```

**There's no such thing as C/C++**.

Answer (score 7):

In C++11:

```
std::string result = "my text" + std::to_string(i);
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming mystring is large enough, which it is in this example:

```
sprintf( myString, "my text%d", 123 );
```

Comment: Sorry, man, but -1 for not using snprintf(). You should really be secure.

Answer (score 0):

With the Qt QString object in C++:

```
std::cout << QString("my text %1").arg(123456);
```